# Can the functions in Gödel's Incompleteness proof be expressed as Gödel numbers?

Tags: incompleteness

I'm trying to understand the entirety of Gödel's incompleteness theorem, and Gödel's proof.

Going by [this English translation](https://www.jamesrmeyer.com/ffgit/godel-original-english.html#g-numbering) Gödel defines 45 **functions (relations)** which build on each other to make the function of provability, there called $Bew(x)$, which returns a `true` if $x$ is a provable statement, and `false` if $x$ is an unprovable statement.

The symbols assigned Gödel numbers are $0, f, ¬, ∨, ∀, (, )$

**Can each of the 45 functions actually be encoded as Gödel numbers?**

*Or are the functions merely manipulation and inspection that we do from the outside to create new Gödel numbers and statements?*

My confusion is that many of the symbols in the functions $(\leq, \epsilon, \exists, \cdot, etc)$ are not simple logical statements. Much is made of the primitive recursion of these statements, but nothing is said about how to actually "write them out"

Comment: FWIW I would strongly recommend a more modern treatment - Godel's original argument was definitely *not* the smoothest way to present the result.

Comment: Thanks Noah. Yeah I think Gödel's original argument is quite obtuse. I've been reading widely about it though, Nagel and Newman is pretty good but obfuscates a lot of the details - and Bryan Bunch's book does a great job at getting the point across but also obscures the 'mechanism' of self-referentiality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gödel numbers are assigned to *expressions* of the language, i.e. to finite strings of basic symbols through the code assigned to the (finite) list of basic symbols of the language: $(, ), \lnot, \lor, \exists, s, 0, +,\ldots$

The basic symbol $+$ has a code, but the sum function: $+(x,y)$ has different codes for every value of the arguments $x$ and $y$.

Thus, we can compute the code of the term $1+0$ as well as the code of the formula $1+0=1$ [i.e. $=(+(s0,0),s0)$]: in both cases the result will be a (very huge) natural number.

What the process of [arithmetization](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan) can do is to generate codes for expressions (formulas) and sequences of formulas.

The meta-mathematical relations and functions, like e.g. $\text {Fml}, \text {Ax}$ and $\text {Bew}$ are relations about numbers that are expressed by formulas.

Thus, due to the fact that we can prove in $\mathsf {PA}$ the theorem $1+0=1$, we can compute its code $c$ and compute the code $d$ of the corresponding derivation (it is a sequence of formulas) and thus we can assert $\text {Bew}(c,d)$.

There is no a "basic" code for e.g. $\text {Bew}$ because it is not a symbol of the language.

But, the provability predicate $\text {Bew}$ is primitive recursive and the machinery of G's Th is based on the proof the p.r. functions and predicates can be "expressed" in $\mathsf {PA}$ (in fact, $\mathsf Q$ is enough), where:

> a two-place numerical relation $R$ is *expressed* by the open formula $ϕ(x, y)$ with two free variables iff, for any $m, n$, if $m$ has the relation $R$ to $n$ [i.e. $R(m,n)$ holds], then $ϕ(m, n)$ is true, etc.

And also:

> The theory $T$ *captures* the two-place relation $R$ by the open wff $ϕ(x, y)$ iff, for any $m, n$, if $m$ has the relation $R$ to $n$, then $T \vdash ϕ(m, n)$, etc.

In conclusion, $\mathsf {PA}$ captures $\text {Bew}$ and thus we have a formula $ϕ(m, n)$ corresponding to it.

This formula is an expression of the language; thus (in principle) we can compute its code.

Comment: This helps a lot! Marked as answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonnyHyman - you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

The set $S := \{n \in \mathbb{N} | \hat{n}$ is provable$\}$, where $\hat{n}$ is the proposition with Gödel number $n$, is a recursive set. This means that there exists a partial recursive function $f$ such that $f(n)$ is defined if and only if $n \in S$.

However, $S$ is not a decidable set. There is no total recursive function $f$ such that $f(n) = 0$ iff $n \in S$. This is because the halting problem would be solvable if there were such a total recursive function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helps me wrap my head around the fact there is no total recursive function $f$ and the notions of undecidability. **I'm still a bit confused though. Can the arithmetical relations be written in the symbolic language itself (and thus have their own Gödel numbers) or are they merely *operations done on* Gödel numbers?**